# Flask - Return a post without redirecting and no AJAX

Tags: python, flask, forms

Is there a way to have a POST submitted from a form that on failure will not change page? For example I want Flask to just return a message that will be displayed below the form instead.

All this without using AJAX

My current code (the json msgs don't work) :

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return try_login(request.form.get('email'), request.form.get('password'))
    else:
        if 'username' in session:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            return """
                <form action="{}" method="post">        
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
            """.format(url_for('login'))

def try_login(email, pswrd):
    if email and pswrd:
        usr = User.get_user_by_email(email)
        if usr:
            if usr.authenticate(pswrd):
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                return {'msg' : 'Wrong Password'}
        else:
            return {'msg' : 'User or Password wrong'}
    else:
        return {'msg' : 'Email and Password are required'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not want to use AJAX, I will assume you do not want to use any other form of asynchronous requests either (partially loading HTML, or JSON).

However, if you want to update any HTML page partially, you will have to make an asynchronous request to the server, and then apply the response to the section in HTML that you want to change.

If you do not intend to make an asynchronous request, you will have to return the HTML page with the messages added.

In your code, for example, you can do something like this:

```
FORM_TEMPLATE = """
<form action="{}" method="post">        
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
"""

ERROR_TEMPLATE = """
<p style="color: red;"> {} </p>
"""

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return try_login(request.form.get('email'), request.form.get('password'))
    else:
        if 'username' in session:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            FORM_TEMPLATE.format(url_for('login'))

def try_login(email, pswrd):
    if email and pswrd:
        usr = User.get_user_by_email(email)
        if usr:
            if usr.authenticate(pswrd):
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                return ERROR_TEMPLATE.format('Wrong Password') + FORM_TEMPLATE.format(url_for('login'))
        else:
            return ERROR_TEMPLATE.format('User or Password wrong') + FORM_TEMPLATE.format(url_for('login'))

    else:
            return ERROR_TEMPLATE.format('Email and Password are required') + FORM_TEMPLATE.format(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: I understand, that is what I was thinking I had to do, but it still reloads the page right? So the user will have to reenter his email/password

Comment: Yes, but if you do not want the user to re-enter the email or password, you can render that in your template and send it back. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to send the password back-and-forth, however.
`'<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value={}>'.format(email)`

Comment: Good idea! Yeah just omit the password, that's usually how it goes